# Error page (response) is not shown when error occurs - customErrors is ON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC application. Here I want to redirect all errors to a custom error page.

I have tried to set this up based on what I usually do + can Google, but still, I don't get the error.

I have the following **web.config**:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
      <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/Index" statusCode="500" />

    </customErrors>
    <!-- More stuff :-) -->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
```

This is my error controller:

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        public ViewResult NotFound()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404; 
            return View("NotFound");
        }
    }
```

I have the following `FilterConfig`:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

However, when I create an error in my Index Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(InvoiceOverviewViewModel vm)
    {
        // used to test error pages :D
        int a = 5;
        int b = 0;
        int res = a / b;
    }
```

Which gives an error, I see the following:

[image]

While my `Index.cshtml` inside the `ErrorController` has the following view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_VerifyLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Danish text that doesn't make any sense here ;-) </h1>
```

What makes it even a bit more weird, is that my 404 page works. This page renders perfectly on localhost ([not on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274235/404-page-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-production-azure-web-app), however).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem #1:**

> While my Index.cshtml inside the ErrorController has the following
>   view...

Your error view is named `Index`, but in in `ErrorController` you try to return unexisting view with name `Error`:

```
return View("Error");
```

Change `ErrorController.Index()` method to:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

or call `View()` without arguments which will default to `"Index"`:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Problem #2:**

`filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`

You should actually remove `HandleErrorAttribute` filter. This filter will process exception thrown by controller action, and it has its own logic for selecting result error view that will prevent display of your custom error page. Particularly, `HandleErrorAttribute` uses "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml". That's the source of error view you see - "An error occurred while processing your request."

Hope this will help. Here are some useful sources regarding error handling in ASP.NET MVC:

- [Demystifying ASP.NET MVC 5 Error Pages and Error Logging](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging)
- [Custom error pages in ASP.NET MVC. Easy, right?](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages)